# Binding authentication state with AngularFire firebaseAuth

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm learning the AngularFire authentication piece at the moment, but have come to a brick wall. I'm trying to figure out how to monitor authentication state in a manner that is accessible by all controllers as well as bindable.

For instance, if the user logs in or out, id like to update a paragraph tag that indicates that state. I'd also like that state to be initially available before the user logs in or out.

Here's the code I'm working with. Basically if I could bind a property between the AuthController and the view called "loggedIn" or something to that effect that updated when authentication state changed, that would be ideal.

```
var dashApp = angular.module("dashApp", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "firebase", "picardy.fontawesome"]);

dashApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }
]);

dashApp.controller('AccountCtrl',
    function($scope) {

    }
);

dashApp.controller('HomeCtrl',
    function($scope) {
    }
);

dashApp.controller('AuthCtrl', ["$scope", "Auth",
    function($scope, Auth) {
        $scope.login = function(email, password){
            Auth.login(email, password);
        };
        $scope.logout = function(){
            Auth.logout();
        };
    }
]);

dashApp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
    function($firebaseAuth){
        var authRef = $firebaseAuth(new Firebase("https://zmdash.firebaseio.com/"));

        var authObject = {
            login : function(email, password){
                authRef.$authWithPassword({
                    email : email,
                    password : password
                }).then(
                    function(authData){
                    }, 
                    function(errorData){
                    }
                );
            },
            logout : function(){
                authRef.$unauth();
            }
        }

        return authObject;
    }
]);
```

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to read [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) and utilize the route/resolve tools mentioned there. These will save you a lot of work dealing with auth. Also check out [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed), which handles auth states and hiding-showing of data.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this as a property on the root scope ($rootscope).  I admit this is hacky, and I believe there are more elegant alternatives using selectively-shared object(s).  But using $rootscope is a dead simple way to share a primitive object from the authentication module to all of the views, such that all views can immediately use it as a native property without constantly including it, calling functions, or implementing their own broadcast listeners.

```
$rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
```

You can initialize it in a module.run() method, or just assume it will be falsey until set by login.

```
authModule.run(["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
};
```

Since scope property are inherited, all views may refer to `isLoggedIn` as a property in the current scope:

```
<li ng-show="isLoggedIn">
    <a href="/#/profile">My Profile</a>
</li>
<li ng-show="!isLoggedIn">
    <a href="/#/login">Log In</a>
</li>
```

I modified your Auth factory to include $rootscope and set `isLoggedIn` as a root scope property when authentication completes.  You would need to add a way to clear this property when the user's token expires.

```
dashApp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", "$rootscope",
    function($firebaseAuth){
        var authRef = $firebaseAuth(new Firebase("https://zmdash.firebaseio.com/"));

        var authObject = {
            login : function(email, password){
                authRef.$authWithPassword({
                    email : email,
                    password : password
                }).then(
                    function(authData){
                        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                    }, 
                    function(errorData){
                    }
                );
            },
            logout : function(){
                authRef.$unauth();
            }
        }

        return authObject;
    }
]);
```

You might want to expand the $rootscope property to be an object including a usernamed and other attributes.

In a more elegant solution, you might add this property to the Auth object, and let views pull it in.  If you do not need this in many views, it might work.  Also, you can use broadcast messages from $rootscope to announce the transitions from logged-in to logged-out, if that is a preferable way to code from.

Comment: Thanks, James.

I ended up doing just that, but I was hoping to ideally avoid cluttering the rootScope as much as possible. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/marcusnielsen/mn-tournament/blob/master/client/components/mn-authentication/repository.js

Can the above file content can be used in a angular factory function to provide what you need?

I can elaborate on the code if it's in the right direction when I'm on a computer and not a phone.